# SiteCore content search Default term boost or proximity or slope of ~0.5 with in the Solr query when searching is done using Content Search

Tags: sitecore

I am facing a Search related issue when using Search using Content Search. We are using sitecore version 8.2 and solr 6.3.0 and Content search for searching. My issue is that during normal search, a term boost or proximity or slope of ~0.5 is being applied by default. We haven't configured any such thing in either sitecore or from code end. This thing is causing failure in providing search result. This boost or proximity or slope is found in the query inside the solr log file. When the same query is being copied and pasted manually in the solr search console fails to provide the result but on the other end when we remove the term boot i.e. ~0.5 from the query and then execute the query then it provides accurate result without fail. We have also checked the same thing inside every sitecore configs present in the solution but haven't found anything such. Following is the solr query that is being found in the Solr log file:
"q=((((_template:(2f2a3eec08c54b22bb507df05670abc8)+OR+_template:(bd467624fd054b88a5739541fa43585e)+OR+_template:(0d04820c1352435f80df403bcaebeef5)+OR+_template:(3aba23653fee4baca44ab3a1337af7f7)+OR+_template:(f7bc6f66a8594c9085151459cf8caa2c))+AND+(title_t:("\\"How+Managers+Can+Encourage+Customer\-Focused+Behavior\\"\~0.5")+OR+_content:("\\"How+Managers+Can+Encourage+Customer\-Focused+Behavior\\"\~0.5")+OR+body_t:("How+Managers+Can+Encourage+Customer-Focused+Behavior"~0.5)+OR+abstract_t:("How+Managers+Can+Encourage+Customer-Focused+Behavior"~0.5)))+AND+(-(_template:(0b2afcd689d44ff5ba7e27b294b702d8)+AND+((-date_and_time_tdt:(0001-01-01T00:00:00Z)++*:*)+AND+date_and_time_tdt:[*+TO+2017-07-14T13:34:09.202Z}))++*:*))+AND+(-(_template:(bd467624fd054b88a5739541fa43585e)+AND+((-date_and_time_tdt:(0001-01-01T00:00:00Z)++*:*)+AND+date_and_time_tdt:[*+TO+2017-07-14T13:34:09.202Z}))++*:*))&fq=_indexname:(sitecore_web_index)&rows=10&version=2.2"

Please revert back to us as soon as possible.

Thanks,

Lalit Joshi

Comment: It seems that you are using “Like” methods in ContentSearch queries. Have you tried to change the query to use String.StartsWith/EndsWith/Contains?

Comment: @Vladimir, you are right. We were using .Contains which applied the proximity. This issue is solved using .Equals() which will query solr in normal manner i.e. without any proximity or boosting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was being caused as we were using .Contains() which applied the normal proximity of ~0.5. This issue was solved using .Equals() which will query solr in normal manner i.e. without any proximity or boosting.
reference: https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/8/t/6990